# In Asp.net can we store a Grid view in session

Tags: asp.net

In Asp.net, Can we save whole gridview with data in session?

I know it is not a good Practice but can we save complete control with data in sessions.

`GridviewEmp.DataSource = TableData;
like Session["GridData"] = GridviewEmp;`

Want to know why can't we save controls in sessions, asked by a senior developer.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? If you know it's not good practice, then it seems it would be better to find a best practice solution rather than this,

Comment: what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm really sure it's technically possible, but there is absolute no good reason to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get datasource of gridview and can save datasource in session.

```
DataTable dt = GridviewEmp.DataSource as DataTable;
Session["GridData"] = dt ;
```

Comment: HI Urvi, Thanks for the reply.I know we can save datatable in sessions but the questions is we can save object type in sessions and why can't we save controls in sessions?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is both yes, and no. Yes you can store any object you want in
sessions, including control instances. But, upon return trips, the instance
you have in session will no longer map to the instance built when ASP.NET
constructs the object model, therefore, any changes made to the object in
session will not be reflected in the page output. The object model is
rebulit on each request.

For More Information [Visit](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/424971-storing-controls-session-variables) Here.

Hope This will help u.

Answer (score 0):

yes we can

```
GridviewEmp.DataSource = TableData;
Session["GridData"] = GridviewEmp;
```

and upon fetching back data from session u need to do this

```
  GridviewEmp= (gridview)Session["GridData"]
```